# issue in installing SPARQLWrapper in python

Tags: python, rdf, sparql

I installed SPARQLWrapper in python
in the installation it shows: 
Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sparqlwrapper-1.4.2-py2.7.egg

egg file are available in sit-packages.

When I tried to import SPARQLWrapper , the program cannot it.
I am new to python and have no clue what are these egg files and how to handle it.

could someone guide me how can i import SPARQL wrapper

Answer (score 2):

An egg folder or zip file needs to exist in your PYTHONPATH.  Normally, eggs in site-packages should be automatically installed in the path.

Execute your python interpreter, eg:

```
python2.7
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

If you don't see `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sparqlwrapper-1.4.2-py2.7.egg` in `sys.path` then either the egg wasn't really installed there, or it's not a valid egg.  If it's there, I'd suggest you're trying to import the wrong module.  Case matters.

You should be able to do:

```
>>> import SPARQLWrapper
```

or

```
>>> from SPARQLWrapper import Wrapper
```

If you're still having problems, please update your question with the actual error message you're getting

Comment: I checked my path and the path exits:    ['', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sparqlwrapper-1.4.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Pyt
hon27\\lib\\site-packages\\rdflib-3.1.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-pac
kages\\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 'C:\\windows
\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: that's very weird... sorry, i don't have so much experience in windows environments, but it should work anyway

Comment: @wikier It's a two-year old question, and he never did tell us what precise message he was getting. Especially from the two different imports.